# Why is the stringstream variable not taking my second input?

Tags: c++, queue, binary-tree, stringstream

`Node` class with 1 default constructor :-

```
class Node
{
public:
    int data;
    Node* left, * right;

    Node(const int data = 0)
    {
        left = right = nullptr;
        this->data = data;
    }
};
```

`main` function to test if `create_tree` is working :-

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "enter the elements of the tree.\n";
    std::string s{};
    getline(std::cin, s);
    std::stringstream ss{};
    ss << s;
    std::queue<std::string> q;
    Node* root{ new Node() };

    while (ss.good())
    {
        ss >> s;
        q.push(s);
    }

    create_tree(root, q);

    std::cout << "root = " << root->data << "\n";
    std::cout << "root->right = " << root->right->data << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

function to create binary tree by taking `root` node & a string queue `q` :-

```
void create_tree(Node*& root, std::queue<std::string> q)
{
    std::queue<Node*> ptr;

    if (q.empty() || q.front() == "N")
    {
        root = nullptr;
        return;
    }

    std::stringstream ss{};
    ss << q.front() << " ";                             //ss << q.front();
    q.pop();
    ss >> root->data;
    ptr.push(root);

    while (!q.empty() && !ptr.empty())
    {
        if (q.front() != "N")
        {
            ptr.front()->left = new Node();
            ss << q.front() << " ";                     //ss << " " << q.front();
            ss >> ptr.front()->left->data;
            ptr.push(ptr.front()->left);
        }

        q.pop();

        if (!q.empty())
        {
            if (q.front() != "N")
            {
                ptr.front()->right = new Node();
                ss << q.front() << " ";                 //ss << " " << q.front();
                ss >> ptr.front()->right->data;
                ptr.push(ptr.front()->right);
            }
            
            q.pop();
        }

        ptr.pop();
    }
}
```

INPUT is given in Level-order with integers & 'N'. 'N' is used to represent that no further branching will take place in that `Node`.

INPUT :-

```
1 2 3
```

DESIRED OUTPUT :-

```
root = 1
root->right = 3
```

in `create_tree`, if i replace the statements (which has comments in its right) with the commented statements, the program is not working. when the program is inside `create_tree`; `ss` is not taking any values inside the `while` loop. i want to know why?

Answer (score 0):

Because std::stringstream is looking for the first delimiter (default is space) and tokenize according to that, it is also keeping a state where it stopped.

The first time, there is no delimiter so it finishes at the end and it works
The second time it finds the space right on the start, so it tokenizes the space.